# Spark Cluster Driver fails with error -

Tags: apache-spark, streaming, hbase, cluster-computing

cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy to field org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$dependencies_ of type scala.collection.Seq in instance of org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD

JavaPairInputDStream messages =KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
                    jssc,
                    String.class,
                    byte[].class,
                    StringDecoder.class,
                    DefaultDecoder.class,
                    kafkaParams,
                    topicsSet
         );

```
     JavaDStream<CustomerActivityRequestModel> customerActivityStream = messages.map(new Function<Tuple2<String, byte[]>, CustomerActivityRequestModel>() {
            /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -75093981513752762L;

            @Override
            public CustomerActivityRequestModel call(Tuple2<String, byte[]> tuple2) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

                 CustomerActivityRequestModel  x = NearbuySessionWorkerHelper.unmarshal(CustomerActivityRequestModel.class, tuple2._2);
                 LOGGER.info(x.getActionLink());
                 LOGGER.info(x.getAppVersion());
                 return x;
            }
        });




     customerActivityStream.foreachRDD(new VoidFunction<JavaRDD<CustomerActivityRequestModel>>() {



        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -9045343297759771559L;

        @Override
        public void call(JavaRDD<CustomerActivityRequestModel> customerRDD) throws Exception {
            Configuration hconf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
            hconf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "localhost");
            hconf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181");
            //hconf.set(TableOutputFormat.OUTPUT_TABLE, hbaseTableName);
            hconf.set(TableInputFormat.INPUT_TABLE, hbaseTableName);
            Job newAPIJobConfiguration1 = Job.getInstance(hconf);
            newAPIJobConfiguration1.getConfiguration().set(TableOutputFormat.OUTPUT_TABLE, hbaseTableName);
            newAPIJobConfiguration1.setOutputFormatClass(org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableOutputFormat.class);

            JavaPairRDD<ImmutableBytesWritable, Put> hbasePuts= customerRDD.mapToPair(new PairFunction<CustomerActivityRequestModel, ImmutableBytesWritable, Put>() {


                /**
                 * 
                 */
                private static final long serialVersionUID = -6574479136167252295L;

                @Override
                public Tuple2<ImmutableBytesWritable, Put> call(CustomerActivityRequestModel customer) throws Exception {


                            Bytes.toBytes("long"),Bytes.toBytes(customer.getLongitude()));
                    return new Tuple2<ImmutableBytesWritable, Put>(new ImmutableBytesWritable(), put); 
                }
            });
             hbasePuts.saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(newAPIJobConfiguration1.getConfiguration());

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The jar you are executing needs to be in the classpath in each node, that solved the same issue in my case.